# Custom 404 and Search result is not showing

Tags: wordpress, seo

I really dont know why is my 404 page and Search Page is not working on my wordpress website. It only shows the header & footer and i check the div content and its empty. For the mean time i used a functions that redirect to a custom page i named it 404. My question is, is it good for SEO, redirecting 404 to specific page?

I used this code to redirect:

```
//404 Page
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'Page_not_found' );
function Page_not_found()
{
    // check if is a 404 error
    if( is_404() )
    {
        // then redirect to custom 404
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/page-not-found-404' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: But what is your opinion about the question?